# Rmarkdown set echo to false be default?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to either set the default echo to FALSE or to make it so that Rstudio will include the `echo=off` when using the CTRL-ALT-I hotkey?

Comment: The GUI RStudio does have chunk options that can be clicked on to easily update chunk options like `echo=off` [shown here](https://community-cdn.rstudio.com/uploads/default/original/2X/8/805526fc3f3b87696471a6a9914848c4c9a8e87d.jpg). You could create a [code snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets) and instead maybe you type CTRL-ATL-Z and this could create your customized R chunk with your options specified to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you are able to set the global knitr chunk options to default to `echo = FALSE`, like so:

````
```{r setup, echo = F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
````

This will allow you to run code chunks with echo set to false be default.

Note, you need to add the `echo = F` to the special 'setup' code chunk.